# Read a CSV file and upload data to correct table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL database with 5 tables and I also have 5 CSV files, one for each of those tables.

I am struggling to create a PHP script that can be used to read each files and then upload the data into the correct table.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

```
<?php
$filename = "test.csv";
//Open the csv file in the read mode
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    //loop into the each row and do the stuff
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
       //$data will have all the related columns 
       //Make sure you will use INSERT query here
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

If you want to write to specific tables there are many way to do so

1. Create 5 files where in each and every file while loop you will have that respective table name.

Eg : Think that you want to insert for customers.csv file

Then in while loop you may use the following way

```
while(/*Code*/){
     //INSERT INTO customers (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2);
}
```

2. In case if your lazy than in one file only you can make a switch operation as follows

   ```
   $filename = 'customers.csv';

   switch( $filename ) {

   case 'customers.csv':

       while(){

           //Insert

       }
       break;

   case 'products.csv':

       while(){

           //Insert

       }
       break;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! With the insert Query how do i make sure that the application is inserting the data into the correct table? The table names are the same as their corresponding CSV files. When you use the insert query the table name must be defined but i need the script to know which table to upload the data.

Comment: @Jack.Crowl Please see the updated answer. Please let me know incase if your looking to any other possibilities so that I can help you

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Is there a faster way of inserting the information into a table. In my insert statement i have about 30 fields and individually listing them makes the code extremely long. I will put an example of the code below.

Comment: '<?php

// Load the Database Configuration file
include 'dbConfig.php';

//Open the csv file in the read mode
if (($handle = fopen("customer.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    //loopinto the each row and do the stuff
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    

      

       $sql = "INSERT into customer(first_name,surname,age,address_line1,address_line2,address_line3,home_number,mobile_number_work_number) values('$data[0]',$data[1]',' etcetc..)
    }
    fclose($handle);

   echo "Data Import Successfull";
}'

Comment: @Jack.Crowl Okay let me check that how to optimize the code of your 30 fields.

Comment: @Jack.Crowl didn't find any good way in case if I get any I will keep you updated. If my answer help you please accept the answer by click of the check mark